# show google drive image with glide in android imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

My drive url is  - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DFHb2-MdGYa2NMUkVtVkZ1V1k/view?usp=sharing

I want to show it in android imageview using glide. I have tried many ways to show it.
Following is my code to show -

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(readExcelFeed.getImage().toString()).into(ivQueImage);
```

Please let me know what is the issue in it.

Comment: Put Uri into load method not String.

Comment: @AslamHossin still it is giving error as SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: Check null pinter exception like 
if (readExcelFeed.getImage()!=null){
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(readExcelFeed.getImage().toString()).into(ivQueImage);
}

Comment: @AslamHossin already added but not working

Comment: post the logcat error...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 following is my logcat error
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: check your URL properly..try with this url: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DFHb2-MdGYa2NMUkVtVkZ1V1k/view`

Comment: @AbhijeetKulkarni did you manage to solve it? I havent had success in the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you want to show just that single image using Glide. Just right click on it, select "Copy image address", then use that as your url String for Glide.

```
String url = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/s6-0yxPhDS4Os7SYbP66RCNp-mDwuKr72mLJx9ekuTWYFPgXahCvj-oVatwXELyVfyZzD80YTaiYde4=w1278-h954-rw";

Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(ivQueImage);
```

Comment: not working. Still having same error as D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: Are you trying to run this in an `AsyncTask`? Please provide your entire class.

Answer (score 12):

Steps for loads image from Google drive into ImageView by Glide Library

Step 1 : In your Drive which image you want to display on ImageView. You need to get shareable link from the three dots from the google drive. like this "https://drive.google.com/open?id=139jBj_GUfmFi_pZN38SS9RMB5wNXMEy9"

Step 2: Then the base url for display the image. link is 
public static String BASE_URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=";

Step 3 : In the Step 1 you see the id of the image then add this id in the base URL. Like this type
"https://drive.google.com/uc?id=139jBj_GUfmFi_pZN38SS9RMB5wNXMEy9"

Step 4 : Use Glide library for display the image on ImageView Like this:

```
Glide.with(mContext)                      
.load("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=139jBj_GUfmFi_pZN38SS9RMB5wNXMEy9")              
.into(holder.user_image);
```

Now you can see your image on your ImageView.

Comment: I tried it `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=` but it's not worked but when I use `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=` it worked for me. As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553199/2462531

Answer (score 0):

For request image source you must use `executeMediaAndDownloadTo()`

```
service.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Then you can get `byte[]` from output stream

```
byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

and insert it to Glid

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.skipMemoryCache(true);
options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);

Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(data)
    .apply(options)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .into(imageView);
```