# How to set google drive image link to imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to set google drive image link to image view, but it showing blank.I tried many ways and i used Glide library also. 
If i am using sample online url it is working.
Here is my link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18F2oNjVUmyX7Kez5r7A6tOlrN0u5oZOr/edit

How to solve this help me please.

Answer (score 14):

You can append the file id to ( "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=") and use the link to load the image in the imageview using GLIDE, ImageLoader, Picasso etc.

In your case, the URL will become (https://docs.google.com/uc?id=18F2oNjVUmyX7Kez5r7A6tOlrN0u5oZOr).

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It is working

Comment: perfectly working

Comment: it works when link sharing is on